# Why does my Angular project on github keeps redirecting?

Tags: angular, github, command-line-interface, angular-cli, github-pages

This angular project I deployed on GitHub pages keep redirecting and I can't figure out why. I can see my angular project for a second and then it gets redirected. Help plz?
https://fodrigoal.github.io/gift-finder

This is the page that appears really quick before it gets redirected:
[image]

The repository is this one (I used the gh-branch to upload it) https://github.com/Fodrigoal/gift-finder/tree/gh-pages

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks fine to me. No redirect of any kind. Problem must be somewhere else. Have you tried with another browser and/or in incognito mode? Does the redirect occur if you try to visit that page from your phone or from another computer?

Comment: It gets redirected in incognito mode, another browser, another computer and my phone =/